# What is the difference between Inkscape and Inkscape-app in MacPorts?

Tags: macports

What is the difference between Inkscape and Inkscape-app in MacPorts?

Their versions differ, 1.3.4 vs 1.2.1.

Their description:

```
Description:          Inkscape.app application bundle


Description:          Inkscape is an multi-platform, Open-Source Vector Graphics
                      Editor that uses SVG as its native file format. This is
                      the current stable release version of Inkscape.
```

`Inkscape.app` seems to depend on `Inkscape`???

What is the difference beyond different versions? Why would you choose one over the other?

Answer (score 1):

`inkscape-app` depends on `inkscape`. `inkscape`'s ‘Port notes’ says

> Install port 'inkscape-app', to create a macOS app launcher.

https://ports.macports.org/port/inkscape/details/

`inkscape-app` creates an app launcher for `bin/inkscape` installed by `inkscape`:

https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/17ee4594c26e335645ce3c5d46cc8da64f0977a5/aqua/inkscape-app/Portfile#L31

Comment: Basically something you can doubleclick to launch? But the downloaded (from Inkscape) version of Inkscape is double-clickable?

Comment: @d-b I would guess inkscape is the version which you must run from the Terminal"s command line and not including an macOS app bundle.

Comment: @d-b see https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/blob/17ee4594c26e335645ce3c5d46cc8da64f0977a5/graphics/inkscape/Portfile#L9 for what inkscape is and I suspect that using the term app launcher here is confusing as it is not a standard macOS term

Comment: @mmmmmm I know what Inkscape, in general, is. Don't know how that link helps?

Comment: It shows what is installed ie just /opt/local/bin/install which is just an executable runnable from command line and not a macOS app bundle (ie what the mac ports inkscape is)